# check if there much id inside dictionary than holds objects

Tags: swift, uikit

I have a dictionary that holds objects, inside that objects I have an id, is there a way to check matches with this id and return the object?

example:
if I have id = 2 and I want to check if there exists in the object and get the particular object that matches with this id

Thanks for the help

my structs:

```
struct CoinsInfo:Codable {
    
    
    let data:[String:CoinSpecificInfo]?
    
}

struct CoinSpecificInfo:Codable {
    let urls:UrlsCoins?
    let logo:String?
    let id:Int?
    let symbol:String?
    

}
```

Comment: `data.first(where { $0.id == 2 }`? But, why is `id` optional? Shouldn't the `CoinSpecificInfo` have all at least an `id`? Etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
// item is an instance of CoinsInfo 
// get a new dictionary with all keys that has id matching in their value
guard let matches = item.data?.filter { $1.id == 2 } else { return }
// get an array of objects
let arr = Array(matches.values)
```